# How to highlight certain dates from database using fullcalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

Hi i want to highlight some dates in fullcalendar plugin. I have those dates in my database.
All i need is to highlight the dates in  my page load using jquery ajax. I can get the dates from the db. It should be highlighted at the time of loading itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#my-div').fullCalendar({
    year: reqDate.getFullYear(),
    month: reqDate.getMonth(),
    date: reqDate.getDate(),
    dayRender: function(daysOfWeek, cell)
    {
        if(reqDate.getDate()==daysOfWeek.getDate())
        {
            $(cell).addClass('fc-state-highlight');
        }
        else
        {
            $(cell).removeClass('fc-state-highlight');
        }
    }
});
```

[Reference](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/dayRender/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. how can i get the dates from db? jqueryajax? what is this reqDate.getDate() and daysOfWeek.getDate()

Comment: you need to change year, month and date by your values get the date in hidden field or you can fetch the dates using $.ajax method and then append all the values one by one to calender